# how to get access to all items of a dynamically inflated layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I dynamically inflate a view which contains spinner and edit text.how to understand which spinner listener is currently working.

```
count = 1;
buttonadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        count++;
        Spinner spin_securityType = (Spinner) MyItem[count].findViewById(R.id.spin_securityType);
        EditText ed_amount = (EditText) MyItem[count].findViewById(R.id.ed_amount);
        SpinnerLogoAdapter spinnerAdapter33 = new SpinnerLogoAdapter(Activity.this.getApplicationContext(),
            securityTpeIcons, securityTpeitems);
        spin_securityType.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter33);
        MainItemLayout.addView(MyItem[count]);

        spin_securityType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView << ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                //how to know which spinner is selected ????????

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView << ? > parent) {}
        });
    }
});
```

what i need is add a validation on one which validates all  5 items at a same time.I have tried setTag but it does not work.please help

Comment: you should be create dynamic spinner and for each spinner set id of that from java code not from xml

Comment: then impments spinner item listener and check in that method which spinner id selected.

Comment: Did you get the solution @Midhum ? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Ram Mandal i have posted the answer.feel free to ask about it if any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. I programatically added id for each spinner and access it inside the listener to know which spinner is selected.For that i added id to the spinner

```
 spin_securityType.setId(id); ex:id=1
```

and access it inside spin_securityType.setOnItemSelectedListener()

spin_securityType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

```
           int Id=parent.getId();//shows id as 1
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```